# Error 400 , speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server, both ports not working

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl

I have a problem with my server, First, I wanted to secure my site, So I created a SSL certificate by using Openssl. This was going reasonable at first.

But every site refused it, because I host 'malware', Since this is not true, because the ads om my site takes you to other sites.

It was reasonable until I tried to turn it on. I had edited / etc / apache2 / sites-available, 000-default.conf, default-ssl, default-ssl.conf, etc.

Now it becomes a bit complex; I knew that my certificates were good, but I had edited the files above to confuse them for the SSL certificates.

The site now shows an error 400 ;

"Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.
Apache/2.4.27 (Ubuntu) Server at hacks4liveprojects.com Port 443"

000-default.conf :   (Mail is in there :()

```
https://pastebin.com/Wuqg4K3p
```

default-ssl:

```
`https://pastebin.com/rDPQdjjE`
```

default-ssl.conf :

`https://pastebin.com/eVr2qkXX`

I hope really that someone can help me out :)

If there is a mistake in grammar, sorry: /

Answer (score 0):

000-default.conf and  default-ssl.conf are redundant, why ? Check your Include directives in the httpd.conf file, don't use redundant configurations.

Try this
in : 000-default.conf : `VirtualHost _default_:443` instead of `VirtualHost _default_:80`